# Write details to a file

Tags: android, file

I want to save some details on the phone that the application runs, but using a txt extension would make it readable.
Is it possible to write the files as binary and not plain text?something unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sharedpreferences. For example like this:

```
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
        save("PUT YOUR STRING HERE");

        Log.e("---> This is it: ", load());
    }  

    private void save(String stringToSafe) // Speichern der Inhalte
    { 
        SharedPreferences shared = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shared.edit();

        String yourString = "The string/value what you want to write into file";

        edit.putString("THE_KEY", stringToSafe);
        edit.commit();
    }

    private String load()
    {

        SharedPreferences shared = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String   get = shared.getString("THE_KEY", "Error");
        return get;
    }
```

For mor you can read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html..

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), [example here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: If I could accept all of your answer I would, thank you all! =]

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreferences. But if you want it only in a file, why don't you encrypt it, or encode it and write it to a file? So when you read from it, just decrypt or decode it.

Pretty simple. You can use Base64 encoding and decoding, and there are lot of examples for it.

Comment: If I could accept all of your answer I would, thank you all! =]